# Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I get the following when I submit my form.

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown column
> 'internal_ref' in 'field list' in
> /home/www/ruckcompliance.site/test_insert2.php:9 Stack trace: #0
> /home/www/ruckcompliance.site/test_insert2.php(9):
> mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO Cus...') #1 {main} thrown in
> /home/www/ruckcompliance.site/test_insert2.php on line 9

It was working fine on my localhost. I've read a few posts and tried different things but can not figure this out.
The column does exist in my database.

```
    <?php

header( "refresh:100;url=customers.php" );

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
include_once 'database.php';

// Prepared statement, stage 1:
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Customer(internal_ref) VALUES (?)");

// Prepared statement, stage 2:
$internal_ref = $_REQUEST['internal_ref'];


$stmt1->bind_param("s", $internal_ref);


$stmt1->execute();

echo "<strong>Record saved....</strong>"; echo 'redirecting to dashboard.';

// Close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username='******';
$password='******';
$dbname = "ruck";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,"$dbname");
if(!$conn){
   die('Could not Connect My Sql:' .mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: [Sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be complete as well as minimal. This sample code is missing the creation of the connection. You can edit out sensitive information but leave the connection code.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added for reference. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error tells you that this column does not exist. You must create it in your database table

Comment: The updated sample shows a default database is selected when the connection is created, which is good info. Does(/did) database `ruck` hold the correct `Customer` table, or a version without the `internal_ref` column? In cases such as this, a `SHOW CREATE TABLE <...>` executed via MySQLi can be informative.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you made mistake in database or php. For example, my name in column name was "pa**s**word" instead of "pa**ss**word".

Comment: no related to excel

Answer (score -1):

There was something wrong with my database table. I originally created the table with SQL I have saved in an excel document.
I recreate my table from scratch within phpMyAdmin and it's now working.
Still trying to figure out what was wrong. The table names where correct.